# Display a reason for a failed QuickCheck property and handle exceptions in the tested function

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a QuickCheck property testing a function `f`. The property maps the function `f` over some list `xs` and checks some element-wise property of the result. In the case of failure, I'd like to display the element of `xs` related to this failure. Consider the following property:

```
prop x =
    printTestCase ("Failed for value " ++ show failure) $ isNothing failure
  where
    failure = fmap fst $ find (not . snd) $ map (\n -> (n, f x n == n)) [10..20]
```

This works fine for the implementation

```
f = (+)
```

and `quickcheck prop` outputs

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests):                  
1
Failed for value Just 10
```

However, if `f` throws an exception, i.e.

```
f = undefined
```

then `quickcheck prop` outputs

```
*** Failed! Exception: 'Prelude.undefined' (after 1 test): 
()
Failed for value Exception thrown by generator: 'Prelude.undefined'
```

How can I write a property which catches this second exception and returns "Just 0"
as for the previous example? I guess, one could use `whenFail` or `whenFail'` for this, but I haven't yet understood the QuickCheck internals.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t define the property for the element type, and let QuickCheck test one element at a time? Then QuickCheck would tell you for what value it fails.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. In my real code, I test equivalency of boolean formulas by comparing them on the exhaustive list of all valuations. The output should give me the first valuation, for which these formulas deviate.

Comment: I changed the question to give a example which is closer to my real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aavogt on the #haskell channel, I found the module `Control.Spoon`, which provides the functions spoon and teaspoon which can be used to solve this problem. However, I don't know how safe it is to use this package (which uses `unsafePerformIO internally`).

Anyway, using `Control.Spoon`, `prop` can be rewritten the following way:

```
prop x =
    printTestCase ("Failed for value " ++ show pureFailure) $ isNothing excFailure
  where
    pureFailure = failure (fromMaybe True . teaspoon)
    excFailure = failure id
    failure g = fmap fst $ find (g . not . snd) $ map (\n -> (n, f x n == n)) [10..20]
```

Wrapping the find predicate with `fromMaybe True . teaspoon` has the effect that find returns
the first element either satisfying the predicate or throwing an exception.

As `teaspoon` can only be used to see that an exception occured, but not which, I use
`excFailure` here so that QuickCheck still sees the exception. The downside is that the find
needs to be evaluated twice. `teaspoon` only evaluates to WHNF, if you need a deep evaluation to trigger the exception, use `spoon` instead.

`teaspoon` catches only a few select exceptions, which is fine for me, because I only really care about undefined and inexhaustive pattern matches.

Comment: I still would like to know whether there is a solution without using unsafePerformIO.